# How can I recover lost commits from a branch

Tags: git, github

I screwed up really bad.
I accidentally merged a branch I shouldn't have into another branch I was working on.
I attempted to undo the merge by doing a

`git push -f origin [WHAT_THOUGHT_WAS_MY_LAST_GOOD_COMMIT_HASH]:my-branch`

Unfortunately this closed the PR I had opened and seems to have erased all the commits I had.

In my PR where the commits would have been I now get the message:

> my-branch was force-pushed and no longer has any new commits.

I can't believe what I just did and there must be a way to recover what had been done previously.

Looking through all old commits in the branch, it seems to skip the date of the commits I had made. It's like they are all just gone.

What happened? Is there any saving this?

Comment: Maybe `git reflog`? What does it show?

Comment: It shows all that I did. Including entering the branch before the screw up. Can I use this to go back to where I was? I am concerned now

Comment: Looks like: http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits Do a backup before?!

Comment: Phew! It is back! Thank you so much.
I just did a `git reset --hard [HASH_BEFORE_MERGE]`

Comment: Ha, cool. As long as you commit you can save almost everything with Git. :)

Comment: @theJuls Just curious. Undoing a merge by doing ... a forced push?! Do you happen to remember where you saw that crazy advice?

Comment: Just my own stupidity. I sometimes do the forced pushes to go back on previous commits, so in my mind of course it makes sense to do the same with a unwanted merge (which at that point had also already been pushed up).